# Bootstrap Dropdown permanently shown - not specific to button click

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-select

I am using Bootstrap, and I am trying to create a dropdown menu, to appear when I click on one of the navigation buttons.

This is how my scripts are referenced:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.icon-large.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/superslides.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery1.9.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="carousel/dist/jquery.superslides.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#slides').superslides();
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This is my html setup:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">CLUB</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SOCIALS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TOURNAMENTS</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

So currently, the dropdown is always shown, rather than just appearing when the 'CLUB' link is clicked. The console is not returning any errors FYI.

Comment: I'm surprised that code isn't showing errors - you're including Bootstrap _after_ you use a method from it (`.dropdown()`)

Comment: Funny, when I put it before, it produces this error:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()')

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle as an example?

Comment: I don't and I'm popping out now, so I can't put it together unfortunately. I'll pursue your point below when I can, thanks for your help - I'll update with any progress!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any other JS / jQuery library that's triggering a click on the dropdown.

For example, FastClick needs to be disabled on Bootstrap Dropdowns, so you might have something similar that's executing a 'synthetic click';

https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because you have set it out with list tags, change your code to this...  Use copy and paste the code below. You can change the text colors in the stylings at the top too.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Dropdown</title>
    
    <style type="text/css">
      .drop {
      
        color: black;
      
      }
      
      a:hover {
      
        color: black;  
      
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <a class="nav-item dropdown drop">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle drop" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"                     role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-                         expanded="false">
          CLUB
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">GALLERY</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SOCIALS</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">TOURNAMENTS</a>
        </div>
   </a>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```